# Need to apply "active" class when in a exact link to NavLink in react router V6

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

React router automatically applies "active" className even to non exact links.

I only need it to give the NavLink the "active" class when the user is in `/solutions/`

But when the user is in `/solutions/web_apps`, it still gives the NavLink the "active" class.

Here's my nav:

```
<nav>
    <div>
        <NavLink to="/"></NavLink>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <NavLink to="/about">about</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/promises">our promise</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/process">our process</NavLink>
        <NavLink exact={true} to="/solutions">solutions</NavLink>
        <NavLink to="/careers">careers</NavLink>
    </ul>
    <NavLink to="/letstalk">let's talk</NavLink>
</nav>
```

This is the link to `/solutions/web_apps`

```
<Link exact={true} to="/solutions/web_apps">
    <h3>...</h3><p>...</p>
</Link>
```

Here are the Routes:

```
<Routes>
    <Route exact={true} path="/" element={<Home />} />
    <Route exact={true} path="/solutions" element={<Solutions />} />
    <Route exact={true} path="/solutions/web_applications/" element={<WebApps />} />
    ...
</Routes>
```

How can I give the "active" className to NavLink only when I'm in `/solutions/` and not when I'm in `/solutions/web_apps` or in any link inside `/solutions/`

Please don't recommend downgrading

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `exact` prop doesn't exist in the RRDv6 APIs for the most part. I think you're looking for the `NavLink`'s `end` prop.

[NavLink](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#navlink)

> ```
> declare function NavLink(
>   props: NavLinkProps
> ): React.ReactElement;
>
> interface NavLinkProps
>   extends Omit<LinkProps, "className" | "style"> {
>   caseSensitive?: boolean;
>   className?:
>     | string
>     | ((props: { isActive: boolean }) => string);
>   end?: boolean;
>   style?:
>     | React.CSSProperties
>     | ((props: {
>         isActive: boolean;
>       }) => React.CSSProperties);
> }
> ```

From the docs (emphasis mine):

> If the `end` prop is used, it will ensure this component isn't matched
> as "active" when its descendant paths are matched. For example, to
> render a link that is ***only active at the website root and not any
> other URLs***, you can use:
>
> ```
> <NavLink to="/" end>
>   Home
> </NavLink>
> ```

Add the `end` prop to the nav links you only want matched as "active" for the path specified.

```
<nav>
  <div>
    <NavLink to="/"></NavLink>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <NavLink to="/about">about</NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/promises">our promise</NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/process">our process</NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/solutions" end>solutions</NavLink>
    <NavLink to="/careers">careers</NavLink>
  </ul>
  <NavLink to="/letstalk">let's talk</NavLink>
</nav>
```